# Java defining objects on the fly

Tags: java, android, object, android-asynctask

So I have a somewhat general question regarding something I came across recently. Let's say have I have 2 classes, Activity and Task. In Activity, a new Task object is instantiated, but instead of being given its usual parameters, some new code is introduced in brackets afterward, and one of its methods is called on that instantiation. I've seen methods being called on an object as soon as it is created, but not re-defining its behavior also. This is all Android based, so maybe it's related to that, but something this syntactically weird seems more like a Java concept than something that Android introduced. Here's the class file:

```
class Task extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        try {
        //do things here
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Exception", ex.toString());
        }

        return Text;
    }

}
```

which is the object to be created, and then the code which instantiates it is here:

```
new Task() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPostExecute(String result) {
                        Log.d("JSON", result);
                        try {
                            if (jObject.has("error")) {
                                //Do something here
                            }
                            else if (!paymentCheck(appDomain)){
                                //do something else
                            }
                            else {
                                //Do last thing
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }
                }.execute(appDomain, email, password);
```

I understand that AsyncTask is a quirky class in that it passes the result from its doInBackground method to the onPostExecute one in a separate thread, and maybe that's why this is done, but I dont really understand why you wouldn't just define onPostExecute in Tasks own class file, like I've seen with other examples. Also, this thing compiles and runs perfectly fine, doing everything it's supposed to to. I just don't really understand the reasoning behind. Hopefully someone here can help! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an Android developer so I'm not entirely familiar with any peculiarities there, but this pattern is used whenever you need to ensure that the response action occurs in a separate thread to avoid deadlocks and the like *or* when the `onPostExecute` manipulates objects that are not visible in `Task`.  This can act as a sort of [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) over any `final` objects that are in scope.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Java syntactic sugar called an [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).